# Why I cant see "two-circle" div tag?

Tags: html, css, forms, tags, github-pages

Here is the html markup and css
I was expecting two circle using div tag on that page

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <header class="signup_header">
                <h1>Signup!!!</h1>
                <p>It will only takes 30 seconds</p>
            </header>
                <main class="signup_body">
                    <form action="#">
                        <p>
                            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="ABC">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="XYZ">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="ABC.XYZ@anything.com">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="at least 8 characters" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="create account">
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </main>
                <footer class="signup_footer">
                    <p>
                        Already have an account?
                        <a href="#login">login</a>
                    </p>
                </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="circle c1"></div>
        <div class="circle c1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.outer-box{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left,rgb(49, 220, 166),rgb(165, 195, 236));
}
.inner-box{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #2773a5;
    z-index: 2;
}
.signup_header h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: black;
}
.signup_header p{
    font-size:0.8rem;
    color: #555;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.signup_body{
    margin:20px 0;

}
.signup_body p{
    margin:10px 0;
}
.signup_body p label{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.signup_body p input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    /* margin-top: 4px; */
}
.signup_body p input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}
.signup_body p input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color: #23628c;
}
.signup_footer p {
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
}
.signup_footer p a{
    color:#1c0ee3;
}
.circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right #ffffffaa,#ffffffff);
    position: absolute;
}
.c1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 30%;
}

.c2 {
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 40%;
}
```

I have tried many different way to both "circle div",  but can't do it properly...
For your reference here is the page link, that i was saying about [signup page](https://souvik-basak.github.io/Signup_Page/)
I was expecting **Two circle on that page using div tag**

Comment: Looks like a typo:  `background: linear-gradient(to top right, #ffffffaa,#ffffffff);` Google Chrome's element inspector will ~~strikethrough~~ any incorrect styling

Comment: The color was just blending in with the background.

Comment: As the circles are really just for visual effect with no semantics attached to them you could consider putting them in as part of the background-image.

Answer (score 0):

As @Harrison said, you have a typo in your `background` property: hex codes are 6 digits, and you need a comma after "to top right". You also have two `.c1` elements instead of one `.c1` and one `.c2` element. If you make these changes the two circles appear

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.outer-box{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(to top left,rgb(49, 220, 166),rgb(165, 195, 236));
}
.inner-box{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #2773a5;
    z-index: 2;
}
.signup_header h1{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: black;
}
.signup_header p{
    font-size:0.8rem;
    color: #555;
    margin-top:5px;
}
.signup_body{
    margin:20px 0;

}
.signup_body p{
    margin:10px 0;
}
.signup_body p label{
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.signup_body p input{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    /* margin-top: 4px; */
}
.signup_body p input[type="submit"]{
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}
.signup_body p input[type="submit"]:hover{
    background-color: #23628c;
}
.signup_footer p {
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
}
.signup_footer p a{
    color:#1c0ee3;
}
.circle{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top right, #ffffaa,#ffffff);
    position: absolute;
}
.c1 {
    top: 100px;
    left: 30%;
}

.c2 {
    bottom: 200px;
    right: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign Up!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer-box">
        <div class="inner-box">
            <header class="signup_header">
                <h1>Signup!!!</h1>
                <p>It will only takes 30 seconds</p>
            </header>
                <main class="signup_body">
                    <form action="#">
                        <p>
                            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="first_name" placeholder="ABC">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="XYZ">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="ABC.XYZ@anything.com">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="at least 8 characters" required>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="create account">
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </main>
                <footer class="signup_footer">
                    <p>
                        Already have an account?
                        <a href="#login">login</a>
                    </p>
                </footer>
        </div>
        <div class="circle c1"></div>
        <div class="circle c2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got this.